# Border Radius Issues styling a table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table look nice with CSS.

I have given a border radius to the heading cells. However - a thin, radius-less, border is being applied on top of my curved border. Chrome says its getting this css from the user agent stylesheet. How can I fix this?

```
#IPTable {
color: #333; /* Lighten up font color */
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; /* Nicer font */
width: 100%; 
border-collapse:separate;
border-spacing: 0;
}

#IPTable th {
background: #3E3E3E;
color: #FFF; font-weight: bold;
height: 40px;
}
#IPTable td {
    background: #FAFAFA;
}

#IPTable td:first-child

#IPTable tr:nth-child(even) td { background: #F1F1F1; }   

#IPTable tr:nth-child(odd) td { background: #FEFEFE; }  

#IPTable tr td:hover { background: #666; color: #FFF; }  

#IPTable tr:first-child th:first-child { 
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0; 
} 

#IPTable tr:first-child th:last-child { 
  border-radius: 0 20px 0 0; 
}
```

Comment: Try adding border-radius: 20px 0 0 0 !important; or     -webkit-appearance: none;

Comment: Hi Ben, welcome to SO! Can you please edit the post and add your HTML table?